# Android Json object and json array sending to httppost

Tags: android, json

I have some data in the database I want to send the data in a json

```
       {"name":"Ram","age":20},
       {"name":"michael","age":25},
       {"name":"Suma","age":28}
```

I want to send all the records to a web api at a time. right now I am sending one by one how can I post this json.How to assign json object to a json array dynamically.?

```
     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
   try {

    obj.put("Name","Ram");
    obj.put("age",20);

    HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 2000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 2000);
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("myurl");
    try {
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
        httpPost.setEntity(se);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpContext); //execute your        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(entity); //if response in JSON format
        System.out.println("Respone: "+jsonString);
```

Comment: create json array with multiple JSONobjects and pass it server via httppost

Comment: Can you answer to my question It would be greate If you can

Comment: be more specific what you want..

Comment: I want to send all the data at one go.

Comment: does that code works?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to create JSON ARRAY..

```
JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray();

JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
    j.put("key",value);
    j.put("key",value);
    myarray.put(j);
JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
    j.put("key",value);
    j.put("key",value);
    myarray.put(j);
JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
    j.put("key",value);
    j.put("key",value);
    myarray.put(j);

JSONObject finalObject = new JSONObject();
finalObject.put("Name", myarray);
```

and then pass **`finalObject`** it as string

Comment: not working for me...my final call encode array as string...i dnt knw why